A Monkey-Pulley Problem
A Monkey of Mass $M$ is hanging on one side of a pulley with a box of Mass $M$ hanging on the other side.
Part (A) The monkey climbs up height $h$ with respect to the pulley. Find the work done by the tension on the monkey.
Part (B) Find the work done by monkey if it moves up height $h$ with respect to string.
I have tried various approaches on the tension of the pulley on the monkey (getting $4Mgh/3$) but still, its wrong.
Can anyone solve this question?
